# Underline in org-mode Literal Example

Tags: emacs, org-mode

According to the [explanation](http://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-examples.html) on Literal Example, literal examples should not be subjected to mark-up. But Is there any way to use any mark-up in literal example?

For example, consider the following literal example snippet.

```
 #+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
 Enter the city you're from: Chicago
 #+END_EXAMPLE
```

I'd like to put an underline at the word Chicago because I want to emphasize that the word Chicago is typed by user. How can I do that?

Comment: I believe my original answer (use of @<u>Chicago@</u>) is incorrect. I got faked out by the header line on the generated HTML, which did respect underline tags. I've deleted my answer so that this question will be seen as not having an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the example to be typeset in the example fashion, you can probably use [emphasis markup](http://orgmode.org/manual/Emphasis-and-monospace.html#Emphasis-and-monospace), at least for the lines that require mark-up. That would be

```
=Enter the city you're from:= _Chicago_
```

I don't think what you request is at all possible, possibly because such blocks seem to be **by design** not subject to mark-up.

For language-specific mark-up, use source code blocks (`#+begin_src`), maybe you can get nicely marked-up blocks using org-mode code blocks (`#+begin_src org`) (though I didn't manage to get "what it looks like" to be exported, I guess that's what in-line org is for).